# Revolution Slider - Lazyload Images for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, revolution-slider

**Problem:** Images become blurry when document width is shrunk because they are too large.

Im trying to lazyload a specific image when the window width is at a value that I have specified. The images are 2560px wide by default.

I am using the latest Revolution Slider and the latest Wordpress version. Images are in .jpg format as they are the smallest. Images MUST be Lazy-loaded because there are 4 different sets of media queries.

The slider has 6 slides and each need an additional 3 or 4 images that will be swapped out depending on the size of the window.

I have read the Slider Revolution Docs but there is no example for my current situation and does not include enough of a technical explanation for me to get an idea of where to start.

**My thinking:**
Load the images using the built in Lazy load function with the 'data-lazyload' attribute, but how would i load multiple images in a single attribute?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [lazySizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) with either this [partial picture/srcset polyfill](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/tree/gh-pages/plugins/respimg) or in combination with either [picturefill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill) or [respimage](https://github.com/aFarkas/respimage).

And then write the following markup:

```
<!-- picture with one implicit density descriptor per srcset -->
<picture>
    <!--[if IE 9]><video hidden=""><![endif]-->
    <source
        data-srcset="http://placehold.it/500x600/11e87f/fff"
        media="(max-width: 480px)" />
    <source
        data-srcset="http://placehold.it/700x300"
        media="(max-width: 700px)" />
    <source
        data-srcset="http://placehold.it/1400x600/e8117f/fff"
        media="(max-width: 1400px)" />
    <source
            data-srcset="http://placehold.it/1800x900/117fe8/fff" />
    <!--[if IE 9]></video(max-width: 1400px)><![endif]-->
    <img
        src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="
        class="lazyload"
        alt="image with artdirection" />
</picture>
```

---

You can also add effects in two ways either a JS animation using the `lazybeforeunveil` event in conjunction with the browsers `load` event or using a CSS transition/CSS animation using the classes `lazyload`, `lazyloading` and `lazyloaded`.

Here are two examples:
1. Simple fadin after load

```
.lazyload,
.lazyloading {
    opacity: 0;
}
.lazyloaded {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 300ms;
}
```

2. fadein while load with spinner (much preferred, if you want to support progressive jpgs or LQIP:

   .lazyload {
       opacity: 0; 
   }
   .lazyloading {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: opacity 300ms;
        background: #f7f7f7 url(loader.gif) no-repeat center; 
   }

Comment: OK, So I added the markup above to a new text layer on revolution slider and after some fiddling.. IT Works! 

One question though, I'm now missing the awesome fade in effects for the slide that is using the text layer for the new images. How would i lazy-load the images to the background layer?

Comment: Returning to this thread, I'd like to thank you for the detailed answer above. 
I managed to implement this perfectly and it has helped our company move forward in terms of creating custom solutions rather than using a plugin for everything. 

Again Many Thanks Alexander!!!